# How to display one result in for loop

Tags: c++

I've this program that is dealing with registration on seminar.

I'v managed to do up the struct class, and also able to list out the seminar.
Currently, I have an issue with the registration.
The problem goes like this:
The user would input the seminar that he would like to register for.
Once the user registered the seminar, it will result that the seminar is either registered successfully (if there's slot), or unsuccessfully (if all slot are taken).

The code that I have is able to print out the result, however it display all the result that it loop through. Is there a way for me to print the result just for that particular seminar that the user had input?

Below is my code.
I understand that I did a for loop.
But I'm not too sure how I can display a single result, without looping it.

Struct:

```
     struct Seminar
        {
            string Title;
            int Capacity;
        };
Seminar theSeminar[4];
```

function:

```
void registerSem(string sem){

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       if( theSeminar[i].Title == sem){
            if (theSeminar[i].Capacity > 0)
            {
                theSeminar[i].Capacity = theSeminar[i].Capacity - 1;
                cout << "Successful registered!" << endl;

            }
            else{
                cout << "Unsuccessful registration" << endl;
            }
       }
       else{
           cout << "Not Found" << endl;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any other way except for std::map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the printing out of the loop. You can do that by adding a `found` variable that you can check afterwards:

```
void registerSem(string sem){
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       if( theSeminar[i].Title == sem){
            found = true;
            if (theSeminar[i].Capacity > 0)
            {
                theSeminar[i].Capacity = theSeminar[i].Capacity - 1;
                cout << "Successful registered!" << endl;    
            }
            else{
                cout << "Unsuccessful registration" << endl;
            }
            break;
       }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Not Found" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

You could also streamline the code by returning from the whole function once a seminar is found:

```
void registerSem(string sem) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (theSeminar[i].Title == sem) {
            if (theSeminar[i].Capacity > 0) {
                theSeminar[i].Capacity -= 1;
                cout << "Successfully registered!\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << "Unsuccessful registration\n";
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could separate the concerns of finding the right seminar and doing something with it:

```
void registerSem(string sem) {
    int found_at = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (theSeminar[i].Title == sem) {
            found_at = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found_at == -1) {
        cout << "Not found\n";
        return;
    }

    if (theSeminar[found_at].Capacity <= 0) {
        cout << "Unsuccessful registration\n";
        return;
    }

    theSeminar[found_at].Capacity -= 1;
    cout << "Successfully registered!\n";
}
```

Comment: OP says: _"Below is my code. I understand that I did a for loop. But I'm not too sure how I can display a single result, without looping it."_ So problem isnt in that it prints all seminars (there is an condition so it prints just one), as you think, but in using loop.

Comment: @FilipKočica Also OP: "*The code that I have is able to print out the result, however it display all the result that it loop through. Is there a way for me to print the result just for that particular seminar that the user had input?*" Your quote says that the problem is that the output is "looped" and not just a single result.

Comment: You still dont get it. OP dont want to use loop to search for seminar, but your code _has_ loop.

Comment: @FilipKočica No, you don't get it. OP wants to use a loop to search for the seminar, but they don't want the output to "loop"; i.e. they only want to display a single result.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the help. That is what I needed.

Comment: But here is an condition `if( theSeminar[i].Title == sem)` which will print only seminar which OP asks for. Also this _"But I'm not too sure how I can display a single result, without looping it."_ is extremely misleading.