# Structure (Search)

Tags: c

I manage to search the name and tel no. but it will also print the "Name not found" whenever the for loop loops.

```
void search(Contact *p, int size, char *tsearch)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(strcmp(p[i].name, tsearch) == 0){
            printf("Name = %s, Tel = %s \n", p[i].name, p[i].telno);
        }
        else
            printf("Name not found!");
    }
}
```

Where should I place 'printf("Name not found!")'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display one result in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847535/how-to-display-one-result-in-for-loop)

Comment: Either you can have a `flag` set implying the result of the search, which can be checked to print "not found" message outside the `for` loop.  Or if you are expecting only one search result, you can have a break after `printf` of result. Condition for not found will be `i==size` here.

Answer (score 1):

2 things. 1 Stop searching after you find the name. 2. Only print if you don't find the name at all (not just the current cell).

```
void search(Contact *p, int size, char *tsearch)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for(i = 0; i < size && !found; i++){
        if(strcmp(p[i].name, tsearch) == 0){
            printf("Name = %s, Tel = %s \n", p[i].name, p[i].telno);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        printf("Name not found!");
    }
}
```

Notice I've added a flag `found` to indicate whether the value was found and stop the loop once it is. And I moved the not found print out to outside the loop only if `found` is still false at this point.